# A word like “anachronism” but for word meanings instead of time

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, vocabulary

I’m trying to find a word that has roughly the same meaning as “anachronism”, but rather than incongruous time periods, it’s the word meanings which don’t line up/don’t make sense with each other.

The sentence which inspired this question was someone saying that they had a few more “sparkles to unfold” (as opposed to secrets, perhaps?). This feels incongruous as sparkles do not unfold. I see examples of mismatched metaphors like this a lot, but I don’t have a word for what they are.

Comment: You've obviously never unfolded a gift in sparkly wrapping paper.

Comment: Could be a *malapropism*

Answer (score 4):

That would likely be a **mixed metaphor**:

> mismatched combination of metaphors

This definition and a description of about 20 other types of metaphors can be found at:

[Changing Minds](http://changingminds.org/techniques/language/metaphor/types_metaphor.htm)

Comment: Best answer, but single-word?

Answer (score 1):

"Incongruity" might be the most apt you can find, and you actually have it already.

incongruity, (n): the quality or state of being incongruous

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incongruity